# Number of keys for a monoalphabetic cipher

Tags: encryption, symmetric

My teacher stated that…

> The number of possible keys (E) in a monoalphabetic cipher is $26$!

My thinking:

> Every letter in the alphabet can be $25$ different letters hence it the  number of possible keys should be $26^{25}$.

What is wrong with my way of thinking, and how did she come to a conclusion of “$26!$”?

Comment: In addition to Nova's answer, there is another error in your thinking: "can be $25$ different letters" looks like you missed the identity. If you exclude that a symbol is encrypted as itself, you add a security weakness (a prominent example of this was the Enigma).

Answer (score 8):

Your teacher is right, and here's why:

What happens if you encrypt `A` with `G` and `B` with `G`? You can't decipher it, because you have no idea if the `G` in the ciphertext was an `A` or a `B`.

So…

- For the plaintext letter `A` you can use the ciphertext letter `A`, `B`, `C`, … , `X`, `Y`, or `Z`. ($26$ possible letters.)
- For `B` you can use `A`, `B`, `C`, … , `X`, `Y`, or `Z`, but not the letter you did use for `A`. ($25$ possible letters.)
- For C you can use `A`, `B`, `C`, … , `X`, `Y`, or `Z`, but not the letter you did use for `A` or `B`. ($24$ possible letters.)
- ...
- For `Z` you can only use the remaining letter. ($1$ possible letter.)

The whole number of possible keys is $26\times25\times24\times [...] \times2\times1 = 26!$ (The exclamation mark denotes the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of a number.)

Answer (score -1):

if s={ a,b,c}

for this , possible combinations {abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba} so its 3!
same way its 26!